# Magento template compatibility

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, template, magento-2.1.4

I am newbie to magento.

I am developing e-commerce portal in Magento 2.1.4.

I have to implement template now. Do i need to purchase only 2.1.4 template only or magento 2.x and 2.1.x template are also compatible with magento 2.1.4?

Any best resource for purchasing template online.

Answer (score 3):

Its not mandatory to purchase **2.1.4 m2 version** compatible themes.

All **2.1x template** will work with your magento version.

But for 2.0x template it will not work with your 2.1.4 version as both 2.0 and 2.1 have major **directory structure changes**.

Themeforest is a good place to get template and theme related resources - https://themeforest.net/tags/magento2

So you can refer that but there are many theme provider available so you need to identify which is best suitable for you .

**Note :** Also To avoid the minors bugs/erros it would be a good to purchase those template/theme which is compatible with your current version (Ex - 2.1.4)